# Parallel random number generation

Tags: haskell, random

I want to execute the very long calculation with random number generations parallely.

```
import Control.DeepSeq
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import Control.Monad
import System.Random.MWC
import System.Random.MWC.Distributions

fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)

main = do
  gen <- createSystemRandom
  let params =  [30, 31 .. 34]
  rs <- forM params $ \n -> do
    xs <- replicateM n $ normal 0 1 gen
    return $ fib n `deepseq` xs
  print $ withStrategy (parList rdeepseq) $ map last rs
```

How to execute `\n -> do ...` parallely?
[monad-parallel](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-parallel) package is not worked well.

Comment: Can you say more than "is not worked well"? What problems did you run into?  Did you try to fix that? Have you tried any other solutions such as the `async` package?

Answer (score 0):

Try forkIO from the Control.Concurrent package:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html

Like this:

```
rs <- forM params $ \n -> forkIO $ do
```